# How to remove all text before and after semi-colon characters

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, editing

In notepad++ is there a way to remove all characters from the first semi-colon to the left, then all characters from the second semi-colon to the right? (including the 2 semi-colons mentioned).

Multiple lines will have different number of characters to the left and right of the first 2 semi-colons... so not sure how it could be done.

**Original line**

```
1943;1943: The Battle of Midway (Euro);Final Burn Alpha;;1987;Capcom;Shooter / Flying Vertical;2P sim;270;joystick (8-way);good;1;raster;;;;2
```

**Line needed**

```
1943: The Battle of Midway (Euro)
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for:

```
.*?;(.*?);.*
```

Replace with

```
$1
```

https://regex101.com/r/iw0dns/1

(Have the regular expression box checked)

Comment: And why are people always trying to edit lists of old video games in Notepad++?  Just wondering.

Comment: Perfect, thankyou. This list is from a Mame set that is used in a front end that displays it this way.. mame uses abbreviated file names for all their roms. I wanted a clean list of the actual name of the rom.

Comment: @drewjbx - If it answered your question, upvote and accept.  Glad to help.